# reinstallimng Anaconda 3 on mac

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, uninstallation

I have been trying to reinstall Anaconda3 on my Macbook pro with no success. I keep getting this error:

> Anaconda3 is already installed in /opt/anaconda3. Use 'conda update anaconda3' to update Anaconda3.

I have followed the discussion on different forums and went through the recommendations to uninstall Anaconda by going through these steps:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
sudo rm -rf /anaconda3
rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
sudo rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
```

and then cleaning backup and deleting the bash file info.

But I had no success and keep getting the same error. I even installed and the uninstalled anaconda from the command prompt but still get this error when I try to install it from graphical install (want to get the app).
At this point I am stuck, would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

I am not 100% sure this is correct, but I had the same problem and put this into my terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/anaconda3
```

So far everything works fine for me. I am guessing that some part of anaconda is installed in a hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just solved it. The error appears because you have a folder called anacondo3 in your mac. I used finder to search for this folder and moved it to the trash. Once this is done, hopefully you can reinstall Anaconda like I could.