# Previously had Anaconda 3, trying to uninstall & reinstall

Tags: macos, anaconda3

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX1a6.png)

A while back I installed Anaconda3 and I thought I uninstalled it.

I deleted all files a.k.a Move To Trash, followed this guide https://setapp.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-mac, and this [reinstallimng Anaconda 3 on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278987/reinstallimng-anaconda-3-on-mac)

*I have a Mac M1 running Monterey 12.1

Nothing is working when I try to reinstall. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing anaconda by revealing hidden files:

```
ls -a
```

It should list all of the files, including the hidden files, in your home directory. You should see something like .anaconda_backup or anything related to anaconda. You can remove this by typing

```
rm -rf .anaconda_backup
```

or if you find any other anaconda directories, you can replace the .anaconda_backup with those as well.

You can then reinstall anaconda.
Hope this helps.